# Reading from the CSV created from Feed Exporter doesn't include updates from the current run

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy 1.4.0 and Python 3.6.3.

I'm trying to read the csv file that's created via "-o items.csv" inside of the "close" method - and then write it to MySQL.  However it only reads what was in the csv file prior to the current run.  Is there a way to close the csv file or another way to force the reading of the csv file in "close" to read the updates made inside of "parse"?

source code:

```
import glob
import csv
import os
import MySQLdb as sql

from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

def product_info(response, value):
    return response.xpath('//th[text()="' + value +'"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract_first()

class Books2Spider(Spider):
    name = 'books2'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ('http://books.toscrape.com//',)

    def parse(self,response):
        books = response.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url,callback=self.parse_book)                

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()           
        rating = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"star-rating")]/@class').extract_first()
        rating = rating.replace('star-rating ','')
        upc = product_info(response,'UPC')
        product_type = product_info(response,'Product Type')

        yield {
        'title' : title,
        'rating': rating,
        'upc' : upc,
        'product_type': product_type
        }

    def close(self, reason):
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'),key=os.path.getctime)

        fr = open(csv_file, 'r')
        csv.reader(fr)
        fr.close()

        mydb = sql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',
        passwd='password',db='books_db')
        print(csv_file)
        cursor = mydb.cursor()

        csv_data = csv.reader(open(csv_file,'r'))

        row_count = 0
        for row in csv_data:
            if row_count != 0:
                cursor.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO books_table(title, rating, upc, product_type) VALUES("{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3]))
            row_count += 1

        mydb.commit()
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Include the code so that it will be easy to understand the question.

Comment: Added code above

Answer (score 0):

I think existing two workaround to bypass your question.

1. using [item pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) provided by scrapy. Implenmenting your own pipeline in `process_item` method which process each item sourcing from `parse_book` and storing the scraped item into MySQL.
2. export csv files when running the spider adds setting via `-o items.csv`,then reading and storing the exports at another script.